# Mark all duplications in annotations

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I need to get queryset where every unique sessionid will be masked as name or something. For example if I have 3 objects

```
{
    "data": "...",
    "session_id": "foo"
},

{
    "data": "...",
    "session_id": "foo"
},

{
    "data": "...",
    "session_id": "bar"
}
```

query should annotate each unique session_id to return:

```
{
    "data": "...",
    "name": "A"
},

{
    "data": "...",
    "name": "A"
},

{
    "data": "...",
    "name": "B"
}
```

How could I make this query? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Does the name annotation refer to the name of the user that belongs to the session or is it just a random name to identify unique records by session_id?

Comment: @Danoram no, there is no user, only session id. I will generate random "name" for each unique sessionid as John Doe. But to simplify this asked as for A, B, C, D, etc.

Comment: Ok so name is just to obfuscate the session_id value. You want to use that instead of the session_id value. gotcha

Comment: @Danoram kind of obfuscation, you are right. I shall hide real session_id and use random name instead for each unique session_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`MD5` database function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#md5) if your purpose is to obfuscate the session id. This will return the MD5 hash of the string:

```
from django.db.models.functions import MD5


Order.objects.annotate(name=MD5('sessionid')).values('data', 'name')
```

I used `.values()` assuming you didn't want the session id. This will return a dictionaries containing only the field `data` and the annotation `name`.

There are also other hashing functions you can use. See [SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#sha1-sha224-sha256-sha384-and-sha512)